# Formatting Large Dollar Values with Single Data Point in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot that is filtering out certain data points based on user inputs. I'm using `d3.format` to return my X Axis values as dollars in the following way:

```
var costFormatter = d3.format('$' + 's');

xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient('bottom').tickFormat(function(d) {
  if (d === 0) { return 0; }
  else if (d < 0) { return ''; }
  else { return costFormatter(d);  } // returns $1.5M, 800k, etc.
});
```

This works effectively when I have a large number of points, but when I get down to a single point on the scatter plot, I have 10 ticks that return numbers like `$8.3498668M`. I'd like the number to appear as `$8.35M`.

*Note: As the domain and range values are dynamic, I cannot explicitly set the values with* `tickValues()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't mix type g and type s in d3.format so you would have to do this...

```
function f(x){
  return d3.format('$,s')(x.toPrecision(3));
}
```

I did some experimenting and the s type seems to include the g behaviour so it's even easier...

```
d3.format('$,.3s')
```

Will give the same result as the above function.

Comment: This seems like the best solution for formatting dollars. Is there a way to conditionally set the number of ticks in d3? I can use an `if` statement in JS to wrap a `.tick()` declaration, but was curious if d3 had a built-in method for doing something like this.

Comment: `axis.ticks()` sets the number of ticks on the axis... Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can `axis.ticks()` accept a function as an argument?

Comment: @Himmel, you can get dynamic tick values from [#linear.ticks()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_ticks) and feed them into `axis.tickValues()`, you can also [nice](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_nice) the domain first.